# λ: folktale data.task - apply an unknown number of Tasks

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, task, folktale

I am wanting to convert a list of id's into a list of `Tasks`, and run them concurrently, similar to `Promise.all`. I am aware of applicatives, but I want to apply an unknown number of tasks so I don't believe that will be the best approach.

Say I have a `Task` that contains an array of `Task`'s.

```
Task.of([Task.of(1), Task.of(2)])
```

Is there anyway to fold the tasks down into a single task that will run them all, or is there a better way that I can handle the data transformation.

The snippet has `data.Task` included that you can copy if you want to provide an example.

http://folktalegithubio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/data/task/

```js
// Task([Task])
Task.of([0, 1, 2])
  .map(t => t.map(Task.of))
  .fork(console.error, console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/bWOZEM.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is `Task`? What library are you using?

Comment: @Bergi, I have added a link to the library (folktale data.task)

Comment: Please avoid editing answers directly into the question.  Let the answer stay in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`control.async.parallel`](http://folktalegithubio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/control/async/index.html#control.async.control.async.parallel) is exactly what you are looking for.

> I am aware of applicatives, but I want to apply an unknown number of tasks so I don't believe that will be the best approach.

That shouldn't hold you back, arrays are traversable and [`sequenceA`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequenceA) would do exactly what you wanted (though quite inefficiently). If it was implemented in folktale, which doesn't feature lists or even a `control.applicative`.

[`control.monad.sequence`](http://folktalegithubio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/control/monads/index.html#control.monads.control.monads.sequence) should have been working the same as the applicative sequence, but unnecessarily uses `chain` instead of `ap`. And `data.task` is problematic anyway in that `ap` is not derivable from `chain` with the same semantics.

Comment: thanks for your help. control.async.parallel is perfect.